# need a way to import a large amount of data into MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a LARGE number of rows like this:

> INSERT INTO `All` (`ID`, `number`)
>   VALUES ('90001', '1');

and 90001 keeps increasing for each row. is there some way to do whis without using that command once for each row?

I'm currently using phpMyAdmin and Microsoft Excell to generate the commands for the next 10,000 rows each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at
[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop-statement.html[1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop-statement.html)

see if that gives you any pointers

Answer (score 1):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: doesn't help me... that's just as bad as me pasting the commands in.

I need a loop so I can tell it what to start/finish at and let it to the rest... not make me generate a list of commands then upload it.